# Help Getting HDMI Output with Bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, bumblebee, output

Running Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. Gnome Shell as interface. 
Graphics card of nVidia GT555M. 
Drivers - Bumblebee and not nVidia's. 
Can get great VGA support (which is also on card) and optimal screen res. 
Optirun works and gives good outputs (125~ frames/sec && 172~ Mpx/sec).
No xorg.conf. Tried getting HDMI output with xrandr but still do not work. Ideas?

```
x@x:~$ dpkg-query -l | grep bumb
ii  bumblebee                                                   3.1-1~preciseppa1                             nVidia Optimus support
ii  bumblebee-nvidia                                            3.1-1~preciseppa1                             nVidia Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
```

Can anyone help me to get HDMI output working? Even while connected to HDMI, screen can get current and indicate that it is connected to a card, but xrandr gives:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3040 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1600x900+1440+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   1600x900       60.0*+   40.0
   1440x900       59.9
   1360x768       59.8     60.0
   1152x864       60.0
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   640x480        59.9
VGA1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   848x480        60.0
   640x480        59.9
   1440x900_59.90   59.9*
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

disper did not help and gave me this:

```
x@x:~$ disper -l
display LVDS1: LVDS1
 resolutions: 640x480, 800x600, 1024x768, 1152x864, 1360x768, 1440x900, 1600x900
display VGA1: VGA1
 resolutions: 640x480, 848x480, 800x600, 1024x768, 1440x900
```

Thank you very much  for your help.

Answer (score 0):

People seem to say that [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/get-hdmi-working-with-nvidia-optimus-on.html) method works. It involves using a separate (non Unity) session for the secondary monitor.